# Not see file NetworkManager.conf in folder /etc/NetworkManager/

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

My network connectivity often gets interrupted when I use the local DNS server at the company, I wanted to change `dns=dnsmasq` to `#dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

But I do not see a **NetworkManager.conf**.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? I have that file on 12.04 but not on 8.04.

Comment: I use ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` just went missing using:

```
dpkg -S /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

My 12.04 has the following as content of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

You might be able just to add that content, and edit that if the file got accidentally deleted. In `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` I have only the file `01ifupdown`, make sure that it is there.

If it has gone missing you can re-install the entire NetworkManager package like so:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install NetworkManager
```